# bash script: get data from a previous line

Tags: regex, perl, bash, grep

I'm trying to pull the resolution for my main monitor in a bash script using the command:

```
system_profiler SPDisplaysDataType
```

It gives me the output:

```
  Displays:
    Color LCD:
      Display Type: LCD
      Resolution: 1440 x 900
      Pixel Depth: 32-Bit Color (ARGB8888)
      Mirror: Off
      Online: Yes
      Built-In: Yes
    PLL2410W:
      Resolution: 1920 x 1080 @ 60 Hz
      Pixel Depth: 32-Bit Color (ARGB8888)
      Main Display: Yes
      Mirror: Off
      Online: Yes
      Rotation: Supported
```

I would like to get the Resolution value for the display that has the value `Main Display: Yes`. I thought I could do it using ggrep with a look ahead, but I've got something wrong:

```
ggrep -P '(?<=Resolution:\s)[\w\d\s\@]+(?=[\n\w\d:]Main\sDisplay\:\sYes)
```

Blergh, sorry for the junky looking regular expression. Any suggestions would be great.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using awk:

```
awk -F' *: *' '/Resolution/{p=$2; next} /Main Display: Yes/{print p; exit}'
1920 x 1080 @ 60 Hz
```

Comment: Very nice and clean. Thanks!!

Comment: This would be the equivalent in perl: `perl -F'\s*:\s*' -ane 'if (/Resolution/) {$p=$F[1]};  if (/Main Display: Yes/) {print $p; last}'`

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't work because the pattern is matched against each line, rather than against the "file" as a whole.

You could load the entire "file" into memory, which is the result of `-0777` in the following:

```
perl -0777nE'say $1 if /Resolution: (.*)(\n {6}.*)*\n {6}Main Display: Yes/'
```

(This is coded so that if order of "Resolution" and "Main Display" get swapped, it won't print anything rather than printing the wrong value. In other words, it fails safely.)

(Use `-e` instead of `-E` and `print "$1\n"` instead of `say $1` if you need to support 5.8 or earlier.)

Comment: Nice, thanks for this example. I'm going with an awk solution because I'm already familiar with the awk command, but I'm writing this down so I can explore it further later because this seems like another logical/safe way of accomplishing the task (I haven't delved into perl yet so it would take me longer to implement).

Comment: -e means command follows rather than script name. -E is the same as -e but enables features. -n means process the input a line at a time. -0777 defines a line to to be the entire file.

Answer (score 1):

Is that fits your need ?

```
system_profiler SPDisplaysDataType | grep -B3 "Main Display: Yes" | grep "Resolution" | awk -F"Resolution:" '{print $2}'
```

Gives : 1920 x 1200 @ 60 Hz (On my computer)

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

You can use `grep`'s `-B` option together with `head` to get the line you want:

```
system_profiler SPDisplaysDataType | grep -B2 'Main Display: Yes' | head -1 | sed -e 's/ *Resolution: //'
```

This would obviously break if the 'Resolution' line isn't exactly two lines before the 'Main Display' line but may not be a problem for you. If it is, then you should probably consider parsing the output into the appropriate tree structure.

Comment: No need for `head` here, `sed -n '1 s/^.*Resolution: //p'` should do. This will also work if there are leading tabs.

Comment: Neat! Thanks for the tip! :-)